# Mac OS Delete files from folder with name recursively

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a main directory with projects. Each project is a folder, like myfolder/projectname. Each project has a directory called var and another directory there called **cache**, like **myfolder/projectname/var/cache**. I would like to prepare a script in Apple script to run Finder recursively through **myfolder** folder, find there all project folders that are like **var/cache** and then remove all files from those folders. For instance:

```
myfolder/projectname1/var/cache
myfolder/projectname2/var/cache
myfolder/projectname3/var/cache
```

How to achieve this? For now I have a code like this but is not working

```
try
    
    tell application "Finder"
        
        delete (every item of folder ("/Users/myuser/myfolder") whose name is "cache")
        
    end tell
    
on error
    
    display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Move the File") buttons {"OK"}
    
end try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished simpler and more efficient with the shell.

`*` are wildcards, the first considers all folders in `myfolder` the second all items in `cache`. `quoted form` is needed if the real name of `myfolder` contains space characters.

```
set baseFolder to POSIX path of (path to home folder) & "myfolder/"
do shell script "rm " & quoted form of baseFolder & "*/var/cache/*"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. I've just added `rm -R ` to be recursive.

Comment: If you want to delete items in a specific folder `-R` has no effect. Strictly spoken this way has nothing to do with recursion.

Comment: This is weird. If I use just `rm` it shows error if there are any subfolders in cache dir. If I use `rm -R` it works

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't expect folders in the cache folder as you wrote *all **files***